# Load unpacked extension is disabled in developer

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to Invoke Chrome through Selenium Webdriver. It was initially working well. For the past 2 days i am getting an error message

[image]

I also noticed that the Load Unpacked Extensions is disabled in my browser.

[image]

And here is the Java Program I use

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\Users\C59122\Desktop\SELENIUM\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
String regur = "https://google.com";
driver.get(regur);
```

Can someone please help me fix the problem?

Comment: Please put the text of the error messages in the body of this question. If you link an image, the text of the error is not indexed and searchable. Also, you may have people who see this post from behind a firewall that blocks your image hosting service. They can't give you advice if they can't read the errors.

Comment: Failed to Load extensions from :

C:\Users\C59122\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4288_11964\internal. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the admininstrator.